# Not getting the newly selected value of RadComboBox OnClientSelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: javascript, telerik, radcombobox

I have Radcombobox like below

```
<radC:RadComboBox ID="Type" Style="padding-left: 2px;" MarkFirstMatch="true"
                    runat="server" Skin="WebBlue" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ResidenceType_SelectedIndexChanged" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="OnClientSelectedIndexChanged" 
                    AutoPostBack="true">
                    <Items>
                        <radC:RadComboBoxItem ID="ComboBoxItem1" runat="server" Text="Home" Value="Home" />
                        <radC:RadComboBoxItem ID="ComboBoxItem2" runat="server" Text="Condo" Value="Condo" />
                        <radC:RadComboBoxItem ID="ComboBoxItem3" runat="server" Text="Rent" Value="Rent" />
                    </Items>
                </radC:RadComboBox>
```

I want capture the newly changed value from the dropdown using j.script. which i am not getting and it is showing previous value.

```
function OnClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs)
       {
            var name1 = "<% =Type.SelectedValue %>";
//  var name1 = eventArgs.get_item();
           alert(name1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function OnClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs)
{
     var item = eventArgs.get_item();
     alert("Selected value: " + item.get_value());
}
```